# List of choices in field 2 depends on selection of field 1

Tags: javascript, form, form-customization

In SharePoint native form, I would like to develop a JavaScript as a web part in the form page (New / Modify)
In **field_1** I have choices between *"Animal", "Vegetable"*
In **field_2** I have choices *"Cat", "Flower", "Dog", "Mouse", "Tree"*
If user choose in **field_1** "Animal" the available choices in **field_2** are only *"Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"*
If user choose nothing in **field_1**, **field_2** stays gray (inaccessible) until user makes his choice.

Comment: which version of sharepoint you are using ? SP Online ?

Comment: Are you using classic experience or modern experience list forms?

Comment: I am using "SharePoint Server 2019"

Comment: I am concerned by the classic experience.